# Powershell parse xml values into csv

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I have an xml file that contains two different values that I am trying to capture in each line.  I am trying to use Powershell to parse them into a csv, two columns, one being Device ID and one being MAC address, with headings.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Below is a sample of what the xml file looks like that I would be working with.  Thank you for your time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeviceConfig>
    <Device RegisterID="1021" MacID="A4F1E85D7D86" />
    <Device RegisterID="1022" MacID="A4F1E85D056E" />
    <Device RegisterID="1023" MacID="A4F1E85CAAEE" />
    <Device RegisterID="1024" MacID="A4F1E85DB284" />
    <Device RegisterID="1025" MacID="A4F1E85D7021" />
    <Device RegisterID="1026" MacID="A4F1E85D034A" />
    <Device RegisterID="1027" MacID="A4F1E85CAD59" />
    <Device RegisterID="1028" MacID="A4F1E85DAFA2" />
    <Device RegisterID="1029" MacID="A4F1E85D050E" />
    <Device RegisterID="1030" MacID="A4F1E85DAF89" />
    <Device RegisterID="1031" MacID="A4F1E85DA80E" />
</DeviceConfig>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace my here string with a call to Get-Content for your actual file, but this works for me, and does not need to bring in .NET classes.

**Code**

```
$xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeviceConfig>
    <Device RegisterID="1021" MacID="A4F1E85D7D86" />
    <Device RegisterID="1022" MacID="A4F1E85D056E" />
    <Device RegisterID="1023" MacID="A4F1E85CAAEE" />
    <Device RegisterID="1024" MacID="A4F1E85DB284" />
    <Device RegisterID="1025" MacID="A4F1E85D7021" />
    <Device RegisterID="1026" MacID="A4F1E85D034A" />
    <Device RegisterID="1027" MacID="A4F1E85CAD59" />
    <Device RegisterID="1028" MacID="A4F1E85DAFA2" />
    <Device RegisterID="1029" MacID="A4F1E85D050E" />
    <Device RegisterID="1030" MacID="A4F1E85DAF89" />
    <Device RegisterID="1031" MacID="A4F1E85DA80E" />
</DeviceConfig>
"@

$xmlData = [xml]$xml

$xmlData.DeviceConfig.ChildNodes | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Output**

```
"RegisterID","MacID"
"1021","A4F1E85D7D86"
"1022","A4F1E85D056E"
"1023","A4F1E85CAAEE"
"1024","A4F1E85DB284"
"1025","A4F1E85D7021"
"1026","A4F1E85D034A"
"1027","A4F1E85CAD59"
"1028","A4F1E85DAFA2"
"1029","A4F1E85D050E"
"1030","A4F1E85DAF89"
"1031","A4F1E85DA80E"
```

With this information, you should be able to make progress...

Comment: I like this approach too.

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank you so much for the assistance!  By using Export-csv instead of ConvertTo-csv, I was able to export to a .csv file like I wanted.  Cheers!

Comment: There is one additional piece of info I would like to add to the beginning of each row in the .csv file.  I have a variable for $servername in my larger script, and I would like to put a column for "Server Name" in this .csv and add the value of $servername in each row (before the RegisterID and MacID).  Any ideas on how to best approach this?  Thank you!

Comment: If I should start a new thread for this, just let me know.  :)

Comment: A new question would be best and in the spirit of SO.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this will work.  Here I am reading the XML from a string, you may be importing it from a file:

```
$xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeviceConfig>
    <Device RegisterID="1021" MacID="A4F1E85D7D86" />
    <Device RegisterID="1022" MacID="A4F1E85D056E" />
    <Device RegisterID="1023" MacID="A4F1E85CAAEE" />
    <Device RegisterID="1024" MacID="A4F1E85DB284" />
    <Device RegisterID="1025" MacID="A4F1E85D7021" />
    <Device RegisterID="1026" MacID="A4F1E85D034A" />
    <Device RegisterID="1027" MacID="A4F1E85CAD59" />
    <Device RegisterID="1028" MacID="A4F1E85DAFA2" />
    <Device RegisterID="1029" MacID="A4F1E85D050E" />
    <Device RegisterID="1030" MacID="A4F1E85DAF89" />
    <Device RegisterID="1031" MacID="A4F1E85DA80E" />
</DeviceConfig>
"@

$csv = `
    Select-Xml -Content $xml -XPath "//Device" `
    | Select -ExpandProperty Node `
    | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

$csv
```

This is the content of `$csv`:

```
"RegisterID","MacID"
"1021","A4F1E85D7D86"
"1022","A4F1E85D056E"
"1023","A4F1E85CAAEE"
"1024","A4F1E85DB284"
"1025","A4F1E85D7021"
"1026","A4F1E85D034A"
"1027","A4F1E85CAD59"
"1028","A4F1E85DAFA2"
"1029","A4F1E85D050E"
"1030","A4F1E85DAF89"
"1031","A4F1E85DA80E"
```

You should be able to write that out to a file if you need.

Comment: This is a good approach.  If the xml is simple and/or you don't need to build queries, I like the '[xml]' type casting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .Net classes here, pure PS won't help. Fortunately, it's easy.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq
$xe = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::Parse($xml)
$xe.Elements() | % {$_.Attribute('RegisterID').Value + ", " + $_.Attribute('MacID').Value}
```

This prints what you need to output. Saving to file is covered by many other replies.

Comment: I actually found that it was not necessary to use .Net classes.  Thank you for your help!